Dice rolling, permutations or combinations?
I came across a relatively common probability question revolving around dice. With probability questions in general, at least at high school level, they can be easily solved by mapping out all the actual outcomes, identifying the number of successful events and the number of total outcomes, and finally dividing the former by the latter.
So coming back to that question, which was:
Two standard six-sided dice numbered 1 to 6 are rolled. What is the probability that the product of the two numbers obtained is the square of a prime?
A) 5/36
B) 3/36
C) 4/36
D) 6/36
E) 7/36
We can easily create the notorious 6 by 6 table of all the outcomes of rolling two dice, and identify the number of pairs that satisfy the requirement:
6 by 6 table with favorable outcomes
-> (2,2) , (3,3) , (5,5) , (1,4) , (4,1)
5 successful outcomes, 36 total.
P = 5/36
And that is indeed the correct answer.
However, I usually like to solve any probability question using permutations/ combinations as well, just to get more practice, but when I tried solving this question using them I couldn't even figure out how to put this question in a formula, I didn't even know which of the two this problem was! and all the ways I've tried gave me absurd results.
The way I usually go about it is ask myself if this is a permutations or a combinations problem, ask myself does order matter? Well I suppose once you roll the two dice, you can move them around, have one in front of the other or the other way around, wouldn't really change which die got which number; order doesn't matter -> combinations. (The way I understand combinations is as a filtering tool for a particular result and not a method in and of itself)
Here's where I entered the first dilemma; just how much should I put into the equation? Do I do each die separately, or do I funnel all the 'items' in the experiment into a pool and create my combinations from them, or both!? so for example, If I wanted to find the probability of getting (2 and 2) or (3 and 3) or (5 and 5) or (1 and 4) do I think of it as:
for the product of primes, out of die 1, I want 1 side rolling once, out of 6 sides rolling once: 1C1/6C1 and(*) from die 2, I want 1 side rolling once, out of 6 sides rolling once:
1C1/6C1. Repeating three times for each of the primes:
(1C1/ 6C1 * 1C1/ 6C1) + (1C1/ 6C1 * 1C1/ 6C1) + (1C1/ 6C1 * 1C1/ 6C1)
or for 1 and 4, die 1, I want any of 2 sides rolling once out of 6 possible sides, and the same for die 2:
2C1/6C1 * 2C1/6C1
this gives the closest answer of 7/36, but I feel like I've just translated what I've found from mapping out the table into combinations, but how do I translate the question or problem into the formula not the answer!
do I think of it as:
out of die 1, I want any of 4 sides rolling once, out of 6 sides rolling once: 4C1/ 6C1, and for die 2, I want the same.
(4C1/ 6C1 * 4C1/6C1)
or for 1 and 4, from die 1, I want any of 2 sides rolling once out of 6 sides: 2C1/ 6C1, and the same for die 2: 2C1/ 6C1 * 2C1/6C1
-> (4C1/ 6C1 *4C1/6C1) + (2C1/ 6C1 * 2C1/6C1)
Maybe something like:
for the product of primes, out of both dice, I want 2 items (e.g. 2 and 2) and I'm rolling twice so: 2C2 out of 12 possible sides: 12C2
-> 2C2/12C2 repeating 3 times for each of the primes -> 3 * (2C2/12C2)
for the 1 and 4, out of both dies, I want 4 sides rolling twice out of 12 sides: 4C2/12C2
-> 3 * (2C2/12C2) + 4C2/12C2 = 3/22
Maybe I don't have to repeat for the different primes, I can just do them all at one:
Out of both dice, I want any of 8 (1,2,2,3,3,4,5,5) or maybe 10? (1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5)
8C2/12C2 = 14/33
10C2/12C2 = 15/22
Or maybe it was never a combinations problem to begin with?
besides, what about replacement/ no replacement? the usual formulas for both combinations and permutations, don't assume replacement, so should I start using n^r? because I don't see what we're replacing here, it's not like once you get a side, you yank it out the die, right? And lastly what about (1,4) and (4,1), are they a permutation or a combination across two different dice, how will the formula know!?
I'm really confused and can't even tell what's going on anymore, But I really wanna emphasize one point again, Is there a method that does NOT feel like I'm just converting the "counting", or the common sense, or the table/mapping out EDIT: method answer, because the whole point of permutations/ combinations is that they allow us to work with huge numbers that are impossible to work out by hand. what if I get a question that has dice with tens of sides or, more than 2 dice?

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

@VincentBatens , hey! thanks for reviewing my post. Do I have to edit my post into mathjax now? I really haven't done it before and kinda spent all day posting this question on different forums, facing technical issues all the time. the math is all simple really, either division or "C" for combinations, I don't even know how else to put it even if I could do mathjax

It's easy to do. For example, for combinations $\binom{n}{k}$ type $\binom{n}{k}$. This is standard LaTeX; many tutorials are out there. This may also help: https://latex.codecogs.com/eqneditor/editor.php

One approach:  for a prime $p$, the only ways to factor $p^2$ (up to order)  are $p\times p$ and $p^2\times 1$.  Thus you need the dice to come up $(p,p)$ or $(p^2,1)$ again, up to order.  There's only one $p$ such that $p^2$ is a possible die face, but there are three primes $p$ which can be a die face.  That makes the count easy.

The point of combinatorics is precisely that it is a "counting" method that works for numbers too large to count on our fingers. So I would say that what you're asking for in the last paragraph is the exact opposite of what you should be looking for. When you have a well-understood model of what it is you want to count, then you may be able to figure out how to use combinatorics to count it efficiently.
You ask what to do if the problem is generalized to more dice or the dice have a greater number of sides. So let's try rolling $r$ fair dice that have $n$ sides each (that is, each generates one of the integers $1$ to $n$ inclusive, independently of all the other dice) and let's see what happens.
To begin with, we can construct a sample space of $n^r$ equally likely outcomes.
This is standard practice and there are many, many answers on this site explaining why this is the right way to measure probability when rolling multiple dice.
(Technically, it's not the only way to define a correct sample space, depending on the question you're answering, but it's never a wrong way to build the sample space for rolling $r$ independent fair dice of $n$ sides each.)
Now to count successful outcomes, we observe that in order for the product of the $r$ rolls to be the square of a prime, we must roll the square of a prime on one die and $1$ on every other die, or we must roll the same prime on two dice and $1$ on every other die.
Conventionally, the function $\pi(x)$ denotes the number of positive primes less than or equal to the number $x$. So there are $\pi(n)$ primes on each die and
$\pi(\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor)$ squares of primes on each die.
Note that $1$ is neither prime nor the square of a prime, so (for example) when we say we have the square of a prime on the first die and $1$ on every other die, there's no way this could overlap the event that we have the square of a prime on the second die and $1$ on every other die.
For the case where we have two dice showing the same prime, there are
$\dbinom r2$ possibilities for which two dice rolled a prime, and each one described an event in which two dice rolled the same prime, disjoint the event described by each of the other $\dbinom r2 - 1$ possibilities.
In each such event, the prime can be any of the $\pi(n)$ primes that appear on each die. Once you know which two dice rolled a prime and which prime those two dice both rolled, you know exactly what number was rolled on every die.
So we now have $\dbinom r2 \pi(n)$ possible outcomes among the total sample space of $n^r$ outcomes.
The other case, rolling the square of a prime on one die, is disjoint from the case of two primes. There are $\dbinom r1 = r$ possibilities for which die rolls the square of a prime, and $\pi(\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor)$ squares of primes that could be rolled,
altogether $r\pi(\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor)$ outcomes.
The probability therefore is
$$ \frac{\dbinom r2 \pi(n) + r\pi(\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor)}{n^r}. $$
For example, let $r = 6$ and let $n = 100.$ Then
$\pi(n) = \pi(100) = 25$ and $\pi(\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor) = \pi(10) = 4,$ so
the probability is
$$ \frac{\dbinom62 \cdot 25 + 6\cdot4}{100^6} =
\frac{399}{10^{12}} = 3.99 \times 10^{-10}. $$
This method uses some binomial coefficients (combinations) to help do the counting, but basically it's still just counting cells in a table of all $10^{12}$ possible individual outcomes (which we thankfully don't actually have to write out explicitly).
That's a good use of combinatorics in a problem like this.

No explanation for the downvote. I could imagine it's for answering a question the downvoter thought was low-quality, but usually people who do that also leave a comment to say that was the reason.

Thanks for the answer. I was actually just reading the answer taking it in. I'm not the one who downvoted.. could be the case you've answered my low quality question but please don't delete the answer just yet!

I didn't think it was a low-quality question; I was merely speculating about someone else's opinion. It seems to me you put a lot of effort into the question to make it represent exactly your understanding of the problem.

"...usually people who do that also leave a comment to say that was the reason." That used to be the case. In the last couple of years, the culture has changed (some kind of backlash?) and now it is quite common, possibly more common than not, to simply down-vote questions and answers alike with no explanation. Sometimes no explanation is needed, but that's not the case here, nor in many other instances. It's a scourge of Math.SE.

@BrianTung Recalling the times when I've recently seen comments a lot like mine, I think your explanation makes sense.
